# AWS API Gateway: Api Event must have a String specified for 'Path'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I'm trying to deploy an AWS API Gateway and a Lambda function using Gitlab CICD pipeline using sam template. Since I want individual stacks for each environment, the **Path** property under **Events** of the Lambda function needs to change with each environment. Below is my code for implementing this:

```
Mappings:
  StackEnv:
    stack-dev:
      envm: "dev"

    stack-qa:
      envm: "qa"

Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        Events:
          MyAPI:
            Type: Api
            Properties: 
              Path: 
                Fn::Sub:
                  - "/${path}"
                  - path: !FindInMap [StackEnv, !Ref AWS::StackName, envm]
```

However, while running the pipeline, an error is returned:

```
[InvalidResourceException('MyFunction', "Event with id [MyAPI] is invalid. Api Event must have a String specified for 'Path'.")]
```

Is this behaviour expected while passing in values using **!FindInMap**? Is there any other way of dynamically passing in the value for **Path**?